# “str.fromCharCode is not a function”

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, methods, push

Im getting the following errors:

1. str.fromCharCode is not a function
2. newStr.push is not a function

I have no clue why I’m getting those errors tbh. I might be using methods the wrong way

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var newStr = str;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str.fromCharCode(str[i] - 13);
    newStr.push(i);
  }
  return newStr;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(
  rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC")
)
```

Comment: The errors are telling you exactly what the problem is: there are no functions called "fromCharCode" or "push" on the String prototype. There's `String.fromCharCode()` on the String constructor itself, and there's the array "push" function. Append to strings by adding more content to the end with the `+` or `+=` operators.

Comment: push will work on array not on string. please update this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
function rot13(str) { 
  var newStr = [];
  for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    let x = String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt()-13);
    newStr.push(x);
  }
  return newStr.join("");
}
```

Comment: This returns an array, not a string, but otherwise it works. The result can be made a string with `newStr.join("")`.

Answer (score 0):

It is [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), not myString.fromCharCode

Lastly you want [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to subtract from

Also you cannot push a char to a string. push is an Array method

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var newStr = []; // using an array - you can use += to concatenate to string
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // I suggest you do not convert the space. 
    // Here I converted it to another type of space but you can use " " if you want
    var x = str[i] == " " ? "\u2005":String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 13);
    newStr.push(x);
  }
  return newStr.join("");
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(
  rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC")
)
```